# TemplateNotFound in Django project using pyjade?

Tags: django, pug, pyjade

I have a `layout.jade` file that contains just a basic skeleton:

```
html
head
body
    header
    block content

    footer
```

In the same directory, I also have a `mypage.jade` file that contains

```
extends layout
block content
    p Hello World
```

Rendering `layout.jade` as a response does just fine. However, when I try and render `mypage.jade` it doesn't go through, and I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to add the explicit directory to TEMPLATE_DIRS in the Django `settings.py`, and everything works